# Custom module redirects to a 404 screen

Tags: database, menu

I created a custom module for my internship, I have to add an item to the users menu in the frontend

- MY ACCOUNT
- ACCOUNT DASHBOARD
- ACCOUNT INFORMATION
- ADDRESS BOOK
- MY ORDERS
- BILLING AGREEMENTS
- RECURRING PROFILES
- MY PRODUCT REVIEWS
- MY TAGS
- MY WISHLIST
- MY APPLICATIONS
- NEWSLETTER SUBSCRIPTIONS
- MY DOWNLOADABLE PRODUCTS
- REGISTER MOVIES`

And I was successful, I added the menu "Register Movies" my problem is that when I click on it it is redirected to a 404 screen, because I have not yet set any PHTML files, I would like to know where I can set this File I already did it once and it worked, but the sidebar with the other menu items disappears, I would like to keep them at the same time that I am in my page.

Like this the same as it is while you are in "My Orders" on the right side>
Shows the "My Account" in the left menu <
[image]

local/Teste/Cadastro/Block/Navegação.php

```
<?php
class Teste_Cadastro_Block_AddSubscriptionLink extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation 
{
    public function addSubscriptionsLink()
    {
        $label = ''; // get label with balance here
        $this->addLink(
            $label,
            "[url]",
            "[title]"
        );
    }
}
?>
```

local/Teste/Cadastro/Helper/cadastro.php

```
<?php
class Teste_Cadastro_Helper extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getSubscriptionsLabel() 
    {
        $label = 'teste'; // get label with balance here
        return $label;
    }
}
?>
```

default/layout/cadastro.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="cadastro">
                <label helper="cadastro/getSubscriptionsLabel" />
                <path>customer/account/teste</path>
                <name>CADASTRAR FILMES</name>
            </action>        
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>`
```

local/Teste/Cadastro/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Teste_Cadastro>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Teste_Cadastro>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <cadastro>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Teste_Cadastro</module>
                    <frontName>cadastro</frontName>
                </args>
            </cadastro>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <cadastro>
                    <file>cadastro.xml</file>
                </cadastro>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
       <routers>
           <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <cadastro before="Mage_Adminhtml">Teste_Cadastro_Adminhtml</cadastro>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
       </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <cadastro module="cadastro">
               <title>cadastro</title>
               <sort_order>71</sort_order>              
               <children>
                   <items module="cadastro">
                       <title>Manage Items</title>
                       <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                       <action>adminhtml/cadastro</action>
                   </items>
               </children>
           </cadastro>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <cadastro>
                            <title>cadastro Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </cadastro>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>  
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <cadastro>
                    <file>cadastro.xml</file>
                </cadastro>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>  
    <global>
        <models>
            <cadastro>
                <class>Teste_Cadastro_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>cadastro_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </cadastro>
            <cadastro_mysql4>
                <class>Teste_Cadastro_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <cadastro>
                        <table>cadastro</table>
                    </cadastro>
                </entities>
            </cadastro_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <cadastro_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Teste_Cadastro</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </cadastro_setup>
            <cadastro_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
             </cadastro_write>
            <cadastro_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </cadastro_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <cadastro>
                <rewrite>
                    <account_navigation>Teste_Cadastro_Block_AddSubscriptionLink</account_navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </cadastro>
            <cadastro>
                <class>Teste_Cadastro_Block</class>
            </cadastro>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <cadastro>
                <class>Teste_Cadastro_Helper</class>
            </cadastro>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config> `


In the config.xml that is showing other codes is referring to another part of my training, I have to do the backend part (which is already working and registering what I need in DATABASE) I just need to do the frontend part now, I need to put in to insert data into a table (register) and view, but only change / delete in the backend, this I already did, I just need the frontend, thank you to anyone who can help.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in layout xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <your_handle translate="label">
       <label>Custom Page</label>
          <reference name="head">
                 <action method="setTitle"><title>Custom Page</title></action> <!--Page Title-->
         </reference>
     <!-- Mage_Customer -->
     <update handle="customer_account"/>
      <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <!-- Your block goes here -->
    </reference>
  </your_handle>
</layout>
```

Update your_handle with your custom controller handle of the new page. `<update handle="customer_account"/>` is responsible for loading the left navigation menu in your page. Also add the add the respective phtml.

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for the help, I tried to modify the xml the way you said, but I did not succeed, the menu item I added disappeared

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to solve the problem with a simple change in the tag "cadastro_controller_index" change to "cadastro_index_index" I had not noticed the problem, your comment was of great help

Answer (score 0):

I've searched the "handle" tag that I did not know what it was for, I have 1 month experience with Magento, I'm still scared of its structure but I see that if you master this tool it is Great, now I was able to add all the elements you requested there, but when I click on my menu item it still opens the page without anything, the phtml file is still white but it also does not get the "handle" I noticed Also that it is not going to the template that I put there, I have to add the "cadastro.phtml" in `<path>` for it to be redirected.

Do I have to make any more changes to some file? I've also been seeing that whoever wears the handle creates observers, would that be the case? In "URL" "title" blocks should I specify the paths or something of the type?

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <cadastro_controller_index> <!-- module here matches node directly beneath <routers> in config.xml -->
       <update handle="customer_account"/> <!-- include existing customer account layout --> 
       <reference name="my.account.wrapper"> <!-- target parent block -->
           <block type="core/template" name="cadastro" template="cadastro/cadastro.phtml"/>
           <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="customer/account/link/back.phtml" /> <!-- add a back link -->
       </reference>
   </cadastro_controller_index>
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>cadastro_filme</name>
                <path>cadastro</path>
                <label>cadastrar filme</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```